# Number of charts required to define a connected smooth manifold of dimension one

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

This question is a subsequent of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806230/does-a-curve-differentiable-manifold-of-dim-1-always-have-a-parametrization/3806251#3806251).

Consider a connected smooth manifold of dimension one. Is is always possible to describe it with an atlas having a single chart?

Intuitively, I would answer positively. However I don’t know how to build a single interval that will map to the full manifold.

Comment: can you find a single smooth chart for the circle?

Comment: Can you cover a circle with a single chart ? - @GageMartin - snap :)

Comment: I feel so stupid with your comments...